# Ihraam wearing for umra

Tags: practical-islam, umrah

Assalamualaikum,

I am in Riyadh this week I went to Jeddah for business trip with my family our company is paying for me & my family all expances.during this trip I planned for umra.but I did not wear the Iraam from Riyadh.i come to Makkah my sister house and after 4 hours I wear the Ihraam and event to Ayeesha masjeth and prayed for Iraam  and perform umra. It's correct or not.